# Navier-Stokes equation apriori estimate

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Assume a Navier-Stokes system of **incompressible** fluid flow. Let the velocity vector has components $\vec{\mathbf{v}} = (u, v, w)$. Are there any ways to obtain apriori estimate of the form $\| w_x \| \leq f(\| u_x \|, \| v_x \|)$, where $u_x$, $v_x$ and $w_x$ are gradients of the first, second and third velocity components respectively and $\| \cdot \|$ is a vector norm?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "vector norm," do you mean something like 3D Euclidean norm at a point in space?  That is, local *a priori* estimates?

I don't see how this could be easily shown.  Imagine an element of fluid being squeezed through a tight hole parallel to the $z$-axis.  Then the $u$ and $v$ components of fluid velocity would become small, and $w$ would become large.  The same would be true of $u_x$, $v_x$ and $w_x$.  So if $w_x$ were forced to become small, it would have to be something global that caused it.

Comment: No, I don't mean a norm at a point in space. I mean some functional space norm. Let it be $L_2$ norm. I always have in mind a continuity equation which imposes some restriction on particular partial derivatives of velocity components. I thought it could be used somehow to show whether such an estimate exists.

Comment: Perhaps, boundary layer behavior might show that there is no such an estimate, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Then I must admit I don't know.  Maybe this reference is helpful: D. Chae : Remarks on the blow-up criterion of the three-dimensional Euler equations, Nonlinearity. 18, No 3, 2005